# Not sure what I am doing wrong - SQL code is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I keep getting this error every time I run this code

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
>   Column 'Vendors.VendorName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is the code

```
select 
    VendorName, VendorContactFName, VendorContactLName,
    sum(InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal- PaymentTotal) as BalanceDue
from 
    Vendors 
full join 
    Invoices on Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
where 
    InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal- PaymentTotal > 0
order by 
    BalanceDue desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you intend:

```
select v.VendorName, v.VendorContactFName, v.VendorContactLName,
       sum(i.InvoiceTotal - i.CreditTotal - i.PaymentTotal) as BalanceDue
From Vendors v join
     Invoices i
     on v.VendorID = i.VendorID
where i.InvoiceTotal - i.CreditTotal - i.PaymentTotal > 0
group by v.VendorName, v.VendorContactFName, v.VendorContactLName
order by BalanceDue desc;
```

Notes:

- You have `sum()` in the `select` but no `group by`.  That is the main problem.
- `full join` is not appropriate.  In fact, you want an `inner join`.  The `where` clause requires that the `invoice` table be matched.  The `group by` requires that the `vendor` table be matched.
- Qualify all your column references.

Comment: Thanks so much all I had to do was just put a group but thanks for the help